# Javascript Text Slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, slideshow

I am trying to add text into a div using JavaScript and/or jQuery and then have that text change to different text every 10 seconds -- so somewhat like a slideshow of just plain text. Here's my code:

```
<div id="textslide"><p></p></div>

<script>

var quotes = new Array();

quotes[0] = "quote1";
quotes[1] = "quote2";
quotes[2] = "quote3";
quotes[3] = "quote4";
quotes[4] = "quote5";

var counter = 0;

while (true) {
    if (counter > 4) counter = 0;
    document.getElementById('textslide').firstChild.innerHTML = quotes[counter];
    counter++;
    setTimeout( // not sure what to put here, 500); // Want to delay loop iteration
}

</script>
```

Comment: The first arg to `setTimeout` is a function. `setTimeout` simply calls that function recursively. So in your case, just put the js code in a function, and then write the name of that function as the first arg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="textslide"><p></p></div>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var quotes = [
    "quote1",
    "quote2",
    "quote3",
    "quote4",
    "quote5",
    ];

var i = 0;

setInterval(function() {
$("#textslide").html(quotes[i]);
    if (i == quotes.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
    else {
        i++;
    }
}, 10 * 1000);
```

**[Working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/CDzXQ/543/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion with plain JS

```
function loop() {
    if (counter > 4) counter = 0;
    document.getElementById('textslide').firstElementChild.innerHTML = quotes[counter];
    counter++;
    setTimeout(loop, 500);
}
loop();
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UMFCy/1/)**

If you want to use **jQuery** you can use this: `$('#textslide p:first').text(quotes[counter]);`

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UMFCy/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use a function and call it on body onload

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        var counter = 0;

        function changeText()
        {
        var quotes = new Array();

        quotes[0] = "quote1";
        quotes[1] = "quote2";
        quotes[2] = "quote3";
        quotes[3] = "quote4";
        quotes[4] = "quote5";

        if (counter > 4)
            {
            counter = 0;
            }

        document.getElementById("textslide").innerHTML = quotes[counter];

        setTimeout(function(){changeText()},10000);
        counter ++;
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="changeText();">
        <p id="textslide"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of while, use:

```
setInterval(function () {
    //do your work here
}, 10000);
```

Comment: It's not _setIntervale_, rather _setInterval_.